# tabbar table view navigation xcode 4

Tags: xcode

I've used the following tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw to make an application with Tabbar and TableView Navigation.

I am using Xcode 4 and I am pretty sure I've done everything right but everytime I click on the tab item which has the TableView, it crashes and I get:

"@synthesize booksArray; Thread 1: Stopped at breakpoint 4"

There is no further specifics, no other mistakes and when I "run for build" it says "no issue".

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have a breakpoint set- it's a bookmark looking thing on the left side of your editing pain. Drag it away and it will be destroyed.